# How to select a row where a col has two characters in a parentheses?

Tags: mysql, regex, select

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE c REGEXP '.*\(..\).*';
```

This didn't work. It returned many rows whose `c` contain string that have more than two characters in `()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE c LIKE '%(__)%'
```

SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6a404/1)

Comment: It misses the cases where there are two Chinese characters in between `()`.

Comment: It actually works, but only for English parenthese, what about for Chinese ones `（__）`?

Comment: `LIKE` may not properly handle one or two multi-byte characters between the parentheses, but you shouldn't have a problem with multi-byte parentheses characters themselves (U+FF08 and U+FF09), since they're provided as literal values in the LIKE pattern.

Comment: Do you mean use `SELECT * FROM t WHERE c LIKE '%（____）%'` should work?  Neither `'%\xff\x08____\xff\x09%'`.  I tested in my application.

Comment: I don't work with MySQL all that much, so I'm not sure how you'll need to escape the multi-byte characters in the SQL statement.

Comment: In a database you're familiar with, how would they be escaped/treated?

Comment: After a quick search, I see that MySQL allows multi-byte literal strings to be encoded via the `_utf8` prefix, as in `_utf8'（__）'` so I updated my example on SQL Fiddle accordingly: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f2e99/1

Answer (score 0):

Your escapes are off.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp

> Because MySQL uses the C escape syntax in strings (for example, “\n” to represent the newline character), you must double any “\” that you use in your REGEXP strings.

Use:

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE c REGEXP '.*\\(..\\).*';
```

Comment: This only works for latin characters in between `()` what if I need to find those cases where the two characters in `()` are non-Latin, for example Chinese characters?

Comment: Not sure if it can be done. "Warning
The REGEXP and RLIKE operators work in byte-wise fashion, so they are not multi-byte safe and may produce unexpected results with multi-byte character sets. In addition, these operators compare characters by their byte values and accented characters may not compare as equal even if a given collation treats them as equal." http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html

Comment: Use `like` instead if you can, see @Fred's answer

Answer (score -1):

How are you running this query? If you're using it in (say) a PHP script, and writing it like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT ... REGEXP '.*\(..\).*';";
```

then the PHP interpreter will actually be stripping out those backslashes, producing the real query

```
... REGEXP '.*(..).*';
```

which would simply be any record that has at least two characters. For this to work properly, you'll have to double-escape:

```
$sql = "SELECT ... REGEXP '.*\\(..\\).*';";
```

PHP will strip off one of the backslashes from each set, leaving the second one to actually reach mysql.

Comment: It's the MySQL parser itself that strips out these slashes, not PHP. Try `echo '\(asdf\)';` in php - the slashes are still there